# XPath, how to select a "checkbox" that is a child to an element with a custom content

Tags: html, xpath

I have a task that requires using some XPath, the site is http://todolistme.net/

So, I need to select a checkbox: `//input[contains(@type, 'checkbox')]`

But before that, I need to add a custom item by typing it into the field and pressing enter, so it appears in a list of "todos". i.e. let's enter "customToDo".

So now I need to select the only one checkbox `//input[contains(@type, 'checkbox')]` which is a child of an `//ul[contains(@id, 'mytodos')]` and contains my custom list item `//span[contains(text(), 'customToDo')]`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get locator of `li` that contains `text` - and select it's `input`:

```
 //li[./span[contains(text(), 'customToDo')]]/input
```